# Obtain relationship between words of a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, parsey-mcparseface

I am working on a project based something on natural language understanding.
So, what I am currently doing is to try and reference the pronouns to their respective antecedents, for which I am trying to build a model. I have worked out the basic part of it, but to complete the task, I need to understand the narrative of the sentence. So what I want is to check whether the noun and object are associated with each other by the verb using an API in python.

Example:

```
method(laptop, have, operating-system) = yes

method(program, have, operating-system) = No

method("he"/"proper_noun", play, football) = yes

method("he"/"proper_noun", play, college) = No
```

I've heard about nltk's wordnet API, but I am not sure whether I can use it to perform the same. Can it be used?
Also, I am kind of on a clock.

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Notes: I am using parsey-mcparseface to break the sentence. I could do the same with nltk but P-MPF is more accurate.

** Why isn't there an `NLU` tag available? **

Edit 1: 
Thanks to alexis, The thing I am trying to do is called "Anaphora Resolution".

Comment: You don't mention whether you're aware of the name for the task you're working on: "anaphora resolution". I don't see what wordnet has to do with it.

Comment: @alexis, I wasn't aware it even had a name. Also, thank you very much for the name, as it will make some things on my part easier.
About the wordnet, I need a lexical database to find synonyms and find verb phrase referent. I just don't know how..!

Comment: Well, take a couple of hours to read on how anaphora resolution is usually approached. You may decide to change your approach. And see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for what you want is "anaphora resolution", or "coreference resolution". It's a hard problem (probably harder than you realize-- nlp tasks are like that), so unless your purpose is just to learn, I recommend you try some existing solutions. I don't know of an anaphora resolution module in the nltk itself, but you can find it as part of the [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) suite. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410282/coreference-resolution-in-python-nltk-using-stanford-corenlp) about how to interface to it from the `nltk`. (I haven't tried it myself).