# Getting character positions in outputs of stanfordNLP in coreference resolution

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use the stanfordNLP for coreference resolution as it is explained [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). I'm running the code of above (provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410282/coreference-resolution-in-python-nltk-using-stanford-corenlp)):

```py
from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient

text = 'Barack was born in Hawaii. His wife Michelle was born in Milan. He says that she is very smart.'
print(f"Input text: {text}")

# set up the client
client = CoreNLPClient(properties={'annotators': 'coref', 'coref.algorithm' : 'statistical'}, timeout=60000, memory='16G')

# submit the request to the server
ann = client.annotate(text)    

mychains = list()
chains = ann.corefChain
for chain in chains:
    mychain = list()
    # Loop through every mention of this chain
    for mention in chain.mention:
        # Get the sentence in which this mention is located, and get the words which are part of this mention
        # (we can have more than one word, for example, a mention can be a pronoun like "he", but also a compound noun like "His wife Michelle")
        words_list = ann.sentence[mention.sentenceIndex].token[mention.beginIndex:mention.endIndex]
        #build a string out of the words of this mention
        ment_word = ' '.join([x.word for x in words_list])
        mychain.append(ment_word)
    mychains.append(mychain)

for chain in mychains:
    print(' <-> '.join(chain))
```

After installing the library:

```
pip3 install stanfordcorenlp
```

downloading the models,

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip
```

and setting the $CORENLP_HOME variable,

```py
os.environ['CORENLP_HOME'] = "path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05"
```

This code works pretty well for me, however, the output only contains information by tokens instead of characters. For example, for the above code, the output is:

```
Barack <-> His <-> He
His wife Michelle <-> she
```

printing the variable *mention* inside the buckle is:

```
mentionID: 0
mentionType: "PROPER"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "MALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
beginIndex: 0
endIndex: 1
headIndex: 0
sentenceIndex: 0
position: 1

mentionID: 4
mentionType: "PRONOMINAL"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "MALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
beginIndex: 0
endIndex: 1
headIndex: 0
sentenceIndex: 1
position: 3

mentionID: 5
mentionType: "PRONOMINAL"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "MALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
beginIndex: 0
endIndex: 1
headIndex: 0
sentenceIndex: 2
position: 1

mentionID: 3
mentionType: "PROPER"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "FEMALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
beginIndex: 0
endIndex: 3
headIndex: 2
sentenceIndex: 1
position: 2

mentionID: 6
mentionType: "PRONOMINAL"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "FEMALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
beginIndex: 3
endIndex: 4
headIndex: 3
sentenceIndex: 2
position: 2
```

I was searching for other attributes, for example, printing ann.mentionsForCoref,

```
mentionType: "PROPER"
number: "SINGULAR"
gender: "MALE"
animacy: "ANIMATE"
person: "UNKNOWN"
startIndex: 0
endIndex: 1
headIndex: 0
headString: "barack"
nerString: "PERSON"
originalRef: 4294967295
goldCorefClusterID: -1
corefClusterID: 5
mentionNum: 0
sentNum: 0
utter: 0
paragraph: 1
isSubject: false
isDirectObject: true
isIndirectObject: false
isPrepositionObject: false
hasTwin: false
generic: false
isSingleton: false
hasBasicDependency: true
hasEnhancedDepenedncy: true
hasContextParseTree: true
```

Despite the great information provided by this attribute, there is no information about the character position of the words. I could split the sentences by spaces, but it is not general, I think that could be cases that it can fail. Can anyone help me with that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `output_format='json'` when you build the client.  The JSON data should have the character offset info of each token.

There is info here about using the client:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html

Comment: You can work out which tokens correspond to the coreference mentions from the coref mentions, and the tokens contain the character offset info.

Comment: Thanks StanfordNLPHelp!!